# On the implication $KJ=K\cap J\,\Rightarrow\,K+J=R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, ring-theory, modules

Let $K=\langle x,y\rangle\subset R=\mathbb C\langle x,y,z\rangle$ be the ideal generated by two out of the three free variables generating the polynomial ring $R$, and let $J\subset R$ be a left ideal such that $R/J\cong \mathbb C^n$ has finite dimension $n$ as a $\mathbb C$-vector space, and satisfies $KJ=K\cap J$.

> Is it true that $K+J=R$ as left $R$-modules?

I think this is true if the following holds. Let $\pi:R\to A=R/[R,R]=\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ be the quotient map, and let $\overline J=\pi(J)$ and $\overline K=(x,y)\subset A$ be the image ideals. Then $\overline K+\overline J=A$. I do not know if this holds. (Geometrically, it means that the finite subscheme $V(J)\subset \mathbb A^3$ does not meet the line $x=y=0$). But if it holds, I think I can write $$R=\pi^{-1}(A)=\pi^{-1}(\overline K)+\pi^{-1}(\overline J)=K+[R,R]+J=K+J,$$ using that $[R,R]\subset K$. Does this sound true?